# Changing image on click Android Listview

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I've got a problem with my code. When you click on an item in the list, it's supposed to change the image displayed next to the text. However, nothing changes when I click.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ChangeImage extends ListActivity {

boolean state1 = true;
boolean state2 = false;
boolean state3 = false;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] {
            "ListItem1", 
            "ListItem2", 
            "ListItem3"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.change_image, R.id.label, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    if(state1){
       ImageView arrowView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.labelimage);
       arrowView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1);}
   else if(state2){
       ImageView arrowView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.labelimage);
       arrowView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);}
   else if(state3){
       ImageView arrowView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.labelimage);
       arrowView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon3);}
   }
}
```

Thank you for your answers ^^

Comment: According to the code you posted, **state1** is always true and **state2** and **state3** are always false. This would cause the arrowView to always be set to R.drawable.icon1. What is the default icon for your image?

Comment: The default icon is icon3

Comment: Is this all the code for your activity? Try putting print statements inside each **if** statement in you onListItemClick method to see if they are ever executed, it could be you are setting all those booleans to false elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set and reset the boolean flag properly,and  change the picture used the touching actions...

`if(state1)
 {              state3=false;state1=false;state2=true;
}`

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you detail it a little?

Comment: use this code:ImageView imageView = (ImageView) lView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox);

Comment: When I try using this code, I get this error : lView cannot be resolved.

Comment: use v instead of lView;

Comment: have you get the solutions?

Comment: The method getChildAt(int) is undefined for the type View

Comment: Oh I just found a way. I used (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox); Thank you for your answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

    switch (position) {
       case 0:
         ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.labelimage);
         imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
         break;
       case 0:
         ImageView arrowView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.labelimage);
         imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon3);
         break;
       case 0:
         ImageView arrowView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.labelimage);
         imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1);
         break;
    default:
        break;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. Eclipse can't compile because you can't have duplicate case. When I tried changing the cases, it didn't make what I wanted my application to do. It switched the first image when I clicked on the second and third position. When an user clicks on item 1, I want the image to change to icon 2 and, when he clicks again, I want it to change to icon 3. Just like what Cut The Rope does with the candy. When you click on the candy it changes to a donut. And when you click again, it changes to a cupcake. That's exactly what I want to do.